# How to attach a listener to an object that takes parameters and returns a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I can see how to attach an event to an object that has no parameters and no return value but how to modify the code below to attach a listener that takes parameters and returns a value?

```
     function attachEventListener(target, eventType, functionRef,
    capture)
    {
    if (typeof target.addEventListener != "undefined")
    {
    target.addEventListener(eventType, functionRef, capture);
    }
    else if (typeof target.attachEvent != "undefined")
    {
    target.attachEvent("on" + eventType, functionRef);
    } 
attachEventListener(mylink, "click", ClickMe, false);
```

I get no error when I do this but it also doesn't fire the event when the link is clicked eithier, Note my functionRef is in this form Test(true, "Hello!"):

```
target.attachEvent("on" + eventType, function() {functionRef});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attachEventListener(myLink, 'click', function(foo, bar) { alert('yay! ' + foo); }, false);
```

Comment: How to return a value? For some reason I can't just add return in front of function.

Comment: I keep getting a type mismatch when trying to attach the function
I am building the function call from variable parameters including the name of the function.

Comment: Just replace `alert()` with `return`… Posting your HTML + JS source might help track down the problem.